# Linux Kernel - GPIO_REQUEST and Sharing GPIOs

Tags: c, linux, kernel, driver, gpio

I am writing a linux kernel driver and am running into a strange issue which perhaps stems from my lack of understanding. The program I am writing is a kernel module that is attempting to do some communication over a GPIO. The communication protocol is simple (toggles high or low depending on what I am passing).

**SITUATION** There is an existing driver that is using a GPIO that I am interested in. It also uses it for communications, but only reads and does not write. My driver only does writing. The communication protocol we both use is the same. My module calls GPIO_REQUEST after the existing driver has set itself up (I do not have access to the source of the other driver).

Any attempt to get the gpio via GPIO_REQUEST will result in the driver resetting itself. I have confirmed this behaviour on the osciliscope.

**QUESTION** How can two drivers share a GPIO? I am assuming that my GPIO_REQUEST call somehow takes away control of the GPIO from the other driver and that calling GPIO_FREE does not fix the situation (causing the reset).

I would ideally like to "borrow" the gpio, set the direction to output, write my data, and then return it back to the other driver.

Note: Willing to modify kernel source if need be.